# How do I do an animated/moving image on the carousel in react. which format is the best?

Tags: reactjs

How do I do an animated/moving image on the carousel in react or rather which format is the best? gif, looping video, mp4, like this one below?

https://www.saloninkdubai.com/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, videos will be smaller than large animated gifs. There are a few key points to keep in mind when using a video over a gif:

1. It should play automatically
2. It should be muted (if you don't mute, chrome won't let you play automatically)
3. It should have have looping on

However, if your video is for some reason larger than your gif file, use the gif. In the end, using one over the other is just a performance benefit if you don't need sound to go with it.

Comment: thanks for the comment! which format for video is the best then?

Comment: MP4, WebM, and OGG are the most common formats that browsers support. If I'm to pick only one I'd pick MP4